# Is there much benefit from removing catalytic converter?

Tags: catalytic-converter, tuning

This is a different question, that question is asking about the implications for an ecu after removing cat.  I'm asking why people remove the cat to begin with and specifically what sort of bhp gains can be expected from doing so.

People with performance cars like to remove catalytic converters however this also has some cons including negative consequences for health and the environment.

However I want to know what are the benefits of removing the catalytic converter.  Is it increased horsepower and weight reduction, if horsepower how much power gain be gained by removing the cat, it seems silly to inhales toxic fumes over a few horsepower, or are the gains far more, how much exactly?

Comment: Also duplicate here : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/35171/10976

Comment: Another possibly relevant question : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/30294/10976

Comment: In terms of weight - given the eeight of a cat, you could benefit more by only carrying 1/4 tank of fuel max as fuel is heavy...

Comment: This topic has been explored extensively in the previously cited questions. If you'd like to have a more open-ended discussion, please visit the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop). We're always open!